# Get Embedded Resource

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

I have a zip file and I added it to my program's resource folder. I set the properties to embedded resource.

Now when I type my.resources. ...in the list the name of that file does not come but other image files comes.

I want to extract the zip file to a folder at runtime. I have done that before if I add zip file to my solution. But if the zip file is added into my resources folder (right click in resources, add, existing item) then how to get it from there.

Help will be appreciated. My program is written in vb.net 2008.

Cheers,
GR

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to add the file as a typed resource. Adding file just to `Resources` folder does not generate resource wrapper property.

[image]

Then you can reference the file content by

```
Dim fileConent As Byte() = My.Resources.FileName
```

Replace the FileName with your file name. Intellisense will guide you.

Comment: @Greatchap - noticed that you never marked answers. Is there a reason for this? Want to make sure you know how to do this.

Comment: Thanks alex. I got it. I guess I was not aware about marking answers. I have marked this one.

Comment: @Greatchap - FYI: you are also capable of up-voting answers and questions.

Answer (score 0):

Modify the property of added resource in solution explorer to "Embedded Resource"