# VS reportviewer how do i create a rdlc file

Tags: reportviewer

I am new to reportviewer and struggling with the concepts.
I realise that I am probably being very stupid here. I have tried reading up on the reportviewer but not found any tutorials except those that drag and drop datasets. which is not what I want to do.

I want to create a report from a single datatable at first just as a learning exercise.

I have created a dataset added the table to it and have tried this code but I get an error: *'The report definition for report "C:\Users\Mike\BM\Reports\" has not been specified. Object reference not set to an instance of an object'*

I don't really understand what the 'The report definition' bit means?

I would appreciate some guidance please.

```
Dim MyTestDS As New DataSet

Dim myTestTable As New DataTable

myTestTable = Data.Accounts.Table.Copy
MyTestDS.Tables.Add(myTestTable)

Dim DSReport As New ReportDataSource()
DSReport.Name = "MyTestDS"
DSReport.Value = MyTestDS.Tables(0)
Dim PathReport As String = "C:\Users\Mike\BM\Reports\"
ReportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportEmbeddedResource = PathReport
ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear()
ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(DSReport)
ReportViewer1.LocalReport.Refresh()
ReportViewer1.RefreshReport()
```

Answer (score 0):

As a learning exercise, I think is better not using embedded resource so you can simply specify the complete report path of your rdlc file; for example:

```
ReportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportPath = "C:\Users\Mike\BM\Reports\YourReportFile.rdlc"
```

If you want to use an embedded report, I *think* you have to get it like this:
[Get Embedded Resource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6464474/get-embedded-resource)

Comment: Thanks but how do I even make an rdlc file?

Comment: I usually recommend http://www.gotreportviewer.com/.
I learn a lot of things from this site when I started using rdlc.

Answer (score 0):

Copy `YourReportFile.rdl` to `YourReportFile.rdlc`